# How can I save a numpy array as bytes using a custom codec?

Tags: python, numpy, compression, pickle, huffman-code

I have a numpy array of type `int8` and shape `(100,100)`. I have used Huffman coding to find a maximally efficient way to encode its contents. For my particular use case, the values I am trying to save are roughly normally distributed around 0 with a standard deviation of about 5 but this question applies to optimally saving ndarrays with any distribution. In my case, extreme values of up to -20 or 20 are observable in rare cases. Clearly it is more space-efficient to Huffman code this type of array than to use standard 8 bit integers. My question is how to do this.

I tried using `np.save()` and using Pickle but was not able to get the efficiency I want. Specifically, for an array of shape `(100,100)` I get a file of size 10,128 bytes using `np.save()`, which makes sense with 1 byte per integer plus overhead. Using pickle, I get a file of size 10,158 bytes, about the same. However, based on my Huffman coding scheme, I should be able to encode the array contents in my particular test case (shown below) in 144 bytes!! (not including overhead)

I tried mapping each integer in the array to its optimal byte string so I have an array of bytes (type `S12`) and then saving that but I get a 118kb file using both `np.save()` and pickle, so that obviously does not work.

Thanks for the help!

Code to reproduce my exact test case:

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np

# Seed random number generator
np.random.seed(1234)

# Build random normal array and round it 
test_array = np.random.normal(0, 5, size=(100, 100))
test_array = np.round(test_array).astype(np.int8)

# Set encoding dictionary
encoding_dict = {6: b'0000',
 -8: b'00010',
 8: b'00011',
 5: b'0010',
 -5: b'0011',
 12: b'0100000',
 -13: b'01000010',
 14: b'010000110',
 -15: b'0100001110',
 -14: b'0100001111',
 10: b'010001',
 7: b'01001',
 -4: b'0101',
 4: b'0110',
 -7: b'01110',
 11: b'0111100',
 -11: b'0111101',
 -12: b'01111100',
 13: b'011111010',
 -19: b'011111011000',
 -18: b'011111011001',
 -16: b'01111101101',
 -17: b'011111011100',
 16: b'011111011101',
 15: b'01111101111',
 -10: b'0111111',
 -3: b'1000',
 -6: b'10010',
 -9: b'100110',
 9: b'100111',
 3: b'1010',
 -2: b'1011',
 1: b'1100',
 2: b'1101',
 -1: b'1110',
 0: b'1111'}

# Save using different methods
np.save('test.npy', test_array)
with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(test_array, file)

# Try converting to bytes and then saving
bytes_array = np.array([encoding_dict[key] for key in test_array.flatten()]).reshape(test_array.shape)
np.save('test_bytes.npy', bytes_array)
with open('test_bytes.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(bytes_array, file)

# See how many bytes it should take
tmp_flat = test_array.flatten()
tmp_bytes = np.zeros_like(tmp_flat)
for i in range(len(tmp_bytes)):
    tmp_bytes[i] = len(encoding_dict[tmp_flat[i]]) / 8
print(tmp_bytes.sum())
```

Comment: `np.save` and `pickle` are closely related.  Essentially `pickle` uses `save` to create the bytestring that it will save.  `np.save` writes a initial buffer with info like shape and dtype, and rest is a byte copy of the array's data buffer.  A `S12` array uses 12 bytes for each element, even for `b'1100'`.  That's not a bit encoding but a bytestring encoding.  So you have replaced each 'int8' byte with 12 bytes!

Comment: `bytes_array.nbytes` is the number of bytes in the databuffer, roughly the same as the `save` size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
tmp_bytes = np.zeros_like(tmp_flat)
```

`tmp_flat` is an `int8` array, so the statement `tmp_bytes[i] = len(encoding_dict[tmp_flat[i]]) / 8` is truncating a lot of digits when it converts a float value to int. Replace the offending line with something like:

```
tmp_bytes = np.zeros(tmp_flat.shape, np.single)
```

But to show how to actually do the compression: I would recommend using [`np.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html), which will actually create an array of 5493 bytes for you.

```
# Make a string of all the data
s = b''.join(encoding_dict[key] for key in test_array.ravel())
# Convert the string into an array
a = np.array(list(map(int, s.decode('ascii'))))
# pack it
result = np.packbits(a)
```

The statement `a = ...` is doing a whole lot of extra work, since it decodes the data, then copies it, then converts a string to an integer umpteen times, etc. Here is a longer, but much more efficient method:

```
s = bytearray(b'').join(encoding_dict[key] for key in test_array.ravel())
a = np.array(s)
a -= ord('0')    # A now contains just 0 and 1
result = np.packbits(a)
```

When you stash this array, make sure that you include the number of bits you expected, rather than the number of bytes. You can unpack to a binary string using [`np.unpackbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html), which supports a `count` parameter specifically for this purpose ([my addition](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10855) by the way).

Final point, use `ravel` instead of `flatten` when you can. The latter always makes a copy, while the former generally does not.

Comment: This did it! Thank you for saving me a few more days trying to figure this out. Also one thing to add for anyone else trying to do this, after calling `np.unpackbits` to get the bit array back into the bytearray you started with you can use `s = bytearray(b'').join(bytearray(chr(element), 'utf-8') for element in a.ravel())`. Took me a sec to figure that part out. Thanks!!

Comment: @thehumaneraser. But keep in mind that `chr(element)` does a conversion to string and then back.

Comment: Good point. Is there a more efficient way to go from a `uint8` to literal bytes? Like going from the integer `1` to the bytearray `bytearray(b'1')`? I was struggling with that for a bit and came up with the code in my last comment but would love to improve its efficiency

Comment: @thehumaneraser. I'm pretty sure you can view as `S1` directly. No need to convert anything. Might need to add 48=='0' to the value first.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you could get a factor of 70 compression on the data you describe. Why do you think that?

Even if the input bytes were constrained to four values, the best you could get is a factor of four compression. (8 bits over 2 bits.) You have a normal distribution with 10 or 11 values just within ±1 sigma.

Maybe you could get a factor of two compression for random bytes with your statistics. On a good day.

*Update:*

Just calculated the entropy of your distribution, assuming a standard deviation of 5. I get an entropy per sample of 4.37 bits. So my estimate of a factor of two was overly optimistic. More like a factor of 1.8.

By the way, you don't need to do this by hand. You can use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) with the `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY` strategy. It will generate the optimal Huffman codes for you.

Comment: Right I had come across zlib before but my problem with it was that it didn't seem to maintain the shape. I will need to be saving this output on a few different array sizes and it will be a real nuisance to keep them all straight so I'm looking for a way to do this while maintaining the numpy header that indicates shape and dtype

Comment: You are right about the factor of 70 compression though. I am currently reviewing how I got that because I realize now that it is out of the ballpark

Comment: Also do you have any resources to recommend regarding calculating entropy? I am trying to wrap my head around that so I really understand what is happening under the hood but I don't quite get how to compute it in a case like this

Comment: A calculator that can do logarithms. The entropy of a set of symbols with probabilities p is the sum over the p's of -p log2(p), in the units of bits.

Comment: Just save the array dimensions with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with this kind of encoding, but I question whether your 144 bytes is an accurate measure.

Your `bytes_array` is 100 elements of 12 bytes each ('S12'), or 12 times the size of the `test_array` (1 byte per element).

If instead we make a list:

```
In [440]: alist = [encoding_dict[key] for key in test_array.flatten()]
In [441]: len(alist)
Out[441]: 10000
In [442]: alist[:10]
Out[442]: 
[b'1101',
 b'10010',
 b'01001',
 b'1011',
 b'0101',
 b'0110',
 b'0110',
 b'1000',
 b'1111',
 b'0111101']
```

and looking that length of those strings:

```
In [444]: sum([len(i) for i in alist])
Out[444]: 43938
```

That's an average of 4 bytes per element.  Even if we can somehow convert those bytes into bits, that's only a 50% compression:

```
In [445]: _/8
Out[445]: 5492.25
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something in general about bits and bytes and counting the size of my elements. In your example, do you mean to say that the data takes up 43938 bits? And that is 5492.25 bytes? I realize now that my estimate makes no sense because even if each item were only 1 bit that would still be 1,250 bytes....

Comment: @thehumaneraser. I've posted an answer that specifically shows you where type conversion is not your friend. Specifically, `tmp_bytes = np.zeros_like(tmp_flat)` truncates all your fractional counts out.